# One instance of combination of column value in MySql

Tags: mysql

I have following columns in the table,

`job_id, company_id, job_status`

Possible job_status values could be - Running, Completed, Failed.

At any given time there should be only one job for a company be in the Running status.
As soon as job is submitted by the person in the company, record is inserted in above table, with status = Running.

Now, no one from the same company (i.e. same company_id) is able to submit the job while a job is running for that company. Once job is completed, job_status is updated to Completed and now job can be submitted for that company.

I want to put this constraint in the database itself, how I can do it in MySql ?

Comment: what does `select version();` show?

Comment: here it is - 5.7.35

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you need a generated column that is the company_id when the status is Running and null otherwise, with a unique index on the generated column.  This prevents multiple rows for the same company having status Running, but allows unlimited numbers of rows with other statuses, since unique indexes don't prevent multiple null values.

Like:

```
create table job (
    job_id serial,
    company_id bigint not null,
    job_status varchar(9) collate latin1_bin,
    running_company bigint as (if(job_status='Running',company_id,null)) unique
);
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=50bddaf86da814a45e1bd02c8621f0a2)